# Javascript function with prototype instead of class

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to make a JavaScript framework for fun. It's been going well so far, but I have one problem: functions with functions added in the prototype.

Code:

```js
const Element = (() => {
    function _element(type, comp = [], attr = []) {
        const el = document.createElement(type);
        comp.forEach(p => el.appendChild(p));
        attr.forEach(a => el.setAttribute(a[0], a[1] === undefined ? a[1] : ""));
        
        return el;
    }

    _element.prototype.event = (name, callback) => {
        this.addEventListener(name, callback);

        return this; //Not sure what to do to make function chaining possible
    }

    return _element;
})();
```

I can use this "class" by using: `const element = new Element()` but, when I try to access the function "event", it is undefined. However, it does show up with Visual Studio Code's IntelliSense.

Comment: You are overriding the return value of your constructor function by returning the HTML element, so of course it isn't going to have the _element prototype. What are you actually trying to do here? I'm guessing VScode intellisense "works" because it assumes that you don't do that, because you really shouldn't do that.

Comment: If you do not use map to make a new array, you should be using forEach

Comment: return _element

Comment: @JaredSmith how could I fix this and achieve the same?

Comment: @epascarello what do you mean?

Comment: @Burperino when you call a function with `new` it does some magic. The `this` pointer is set to the instance being created, and the function has an implicit return value of that instance (an invisible `return this;`). When you override that implicit return of this (which has the prototype you expect) with something else, the created instance is basically just discarded, which is why you shouldn't do that, and why you can't do it in a class constructor. If you want an HTMLElement to have a method on it's prototype, then you'd have to modify that prototype. Which you should never ever do.

Comment: No worries. If you have more specifics about what you're trying to accomplish, I may be able to suggest a better pattern, but that's why the code in your example doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using "regular" ES6 classes?

Comment: Within the constructor `_element` the OP has to skip returning `el` but make it part of every instance like `this.el = document.createElement(type);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jared Smith pointed out you're overriding the return value of your constructor by returning an html element. Arrow functions also don't give you access to the `this` context so chaining wouldn't have worked.

```
const Element = (() => {
    function _element(type, comp = [], attr = []) {
        this.el = document.createElement(type);
        comp.forEach(p => this.el.appendChild(p));
        attr.forEach(a => this.el.setAttribute(a[0], a[1] === undefined ? a[1] : ""));
        
    }

    _element.prototype.event = function(name, callback) {
        this.el.addEventListener(name, callback);
        return this;
    }

    return _element;
})();
```

Comment: Than you for your time.